# What makes a python tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

The following code does not print what I would expect:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print type(1,)
a = 1,
print type(a)
```

Here is the output:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'tuple'>
```

I understand that the comma makes a into a tuple.  But if that is the case how come the original print is not printing a tuple type but an int?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the tuple syntax inside a function call is also the way parameters are passed:

```
>>> print type(1,2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments

>>> print type((1,))
<type 'tuple'>

>>> a = 1,
>>> type(a)
<type 'tuple'>
```

It is a syntax ambiguity for python, which it solves by deciding that you are trying to pass a parameter (if you ask me, it should be a syntax error though).

```
>>> print type(1,)
>>> print type(1)
```

Are the same.

Comment: While the point is definitely arguable, the reason it *isn't* a `SyntaxError` to include a trailing comma in an argument list is to maintain consistency between `(1,)` and `tuple(1,)` and `[1,]` and `list(1,)`.

Answer (score 1):

`type()` is a function, so the python parser will pass everything between the parenthesis of the `type` function call as the argument tuple to that function.

Thus, to pass a literal tuple to a function call you'll always need to add the parenthesis to the tuple for the parser to recognize it as such:

```
print type((1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not enclosed in parentheses: `type((1,))`

Without the extra parentheses it's treated as a simple parameter list in this context and the trailing semicolon is simply ignored.